# Get thing-at-point to include periods

Tags: copy-paste, syntax-table, avy

I'm using avy to select and insert symbols on screen with the help of `thing-at-point`. Is there an obvious way to get this to include periods? At the moment if I select `self.blah` I get just `self` (or `blah`).

I can <del>obviously</del> do this using regular expressions, `save-excursion`, and searching back and forward. But a standard approach seems less verbose and likely a better thing to learn.

Comment: I had a quick look at the thing-at-point source code and it seems fairly easy to define a custom thing... but this seems rather like overkill in this case.

Comment: Well here is my horrible approach it works provided you are english and don't like diacritics. Pasting this inline because answering one's own question too quickly is bad: `(setq extended-word-re  "[^a-zA-Z0-9.]")
 (defun my-extended-word-at-point ()
  (save-excursion
    (buffer-substring-no-properties
     (progn
       (search-backward-regexp extended-word-re)
       (forward-char)
       (point)
       )

     (progn
       (forward-char)
       (search-forward-regexp extended-word-re)
       (point)
       (backward-char)
       (point)))))` better approaches appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this.

```el
(defun dotted-symbol-at-point ()
  (with-syntax-table (make-syntax-table (syntax-table))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?. "_")
    (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
```